# Revealing a hidden div and jumping down to it at the same time on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

I'm currently working on a site that has a hidden section (schedule, rates). When you click a link button it is supposed to reveal that section and jump down to it. I can only get one or the other thing to happen. I'm using an anchor tag to do the jump to a div id="extracontent" and I'm using a javascript function to hide and then reveal the content. But if it is hidden it just jumps down a little bit when it is revealed. If you click the button again, it jumps down fine. I'm pretty sure this is a timing thing but as I'm a complete newb when it comes to jquery or javascript I have no idea how to handle this.

You can check out the site here: http://www.davidarabis.com/OYoga/

Hope I was clear and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add an onclick handler to your "slick-toggle" anchor element in HTML, like so:

```
<a onclick="$('#extracontent').show();" id="slick-toggle" class="schedule" href="#extracontent">Check out our Schedule &amp; Rates</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the one I wound up using.

Comment: +1 for a nice simple solution, making use of event propagation.

Comment: @xoam - btw, you should accept this answer as you say it is the solution you ended up using successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#slick-toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#extracontent').show(400, function() {
       window.location = $('#slick-toggle').attr('href');
   });       
});
```

It should show the content and then change the url to include the anchor. It is untested though.

Comment: Pasting the above into Chromium's console, and then clicking the `$('#slick-toggle')` link results in a 404 page. Chromium 9.0.x/Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, was using $(this) inside the callback which was obviously a reference to the new div rather than the link. Updated the answer now.

Comment: The page in question already seems to navigate to that location, however it's not really working. Perhaps a `scrollTop` animation would be effective here?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, try this:

```
$('#my-div').show('normal', function() {
        window.location = '#anchor-name';
    });
```

Otherwise, you may also make it better by:

```
var pos = $('#my-div').show('normal').offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pos + 'px' }, 'normal', 'swing');
```

Comment: I like your `'html, body'` selector. Handles Gecko, IE, and more importantly the out-lier: Webkit all in one go.